# jQuery delegated click event to datetimepicker need to click twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetimepicker, event-bubbling

I have content that is dynamically added into the index page via ajax calls with the history api (I use pushstate and onpopstate).

For a specific page that will be loaded I have a form with a date field like this:

```
<tr>
  <td class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
    <input style='width: 250px; border: 0; outline: none; name='invoicedate' value='2017-10-01' data-date-format='YYYY-MM-DD'>
    <span class='input-group-addon'>
      <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-calendar'></span>
    </span>
  </td>
</tr>
```

from the index page I want to attach a click event to datetimepicker1 so that the Bootstrap datetimepicker widget will show. I use this snippet:

```
$("#container").on("click", "#datetimepicker1", function(){
  $("#datetimepicker1").datetimepicker({
    locale: 'nl',
    format: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
    allowInputToggle: true,
    useCurrent: false,
  }); 
});
```

The problem is that I need to click twice on the datepicker before the widget shows up.

After doing that the datepicker shows up directly when clicked for the third time.

I have tried to wrap the above with $(document).ready(function () { } but that didnt work, because I think the added content with ajax calls via innerhtml doesn't fire a page reload. Also some people said to use delegated events which I do as you can see and it still doesn't work.

Anyone got thoughts on this why this happens? I also tried to inspect the code with Google Developer tools from the console pane: monitorEvents(window, "click") and $._data(($0), 'events') but it is too verbose and I don't know how to use the information for debugging like event bubbling.

Thanks for helping!

Comment: I don't use jQuery, but I would imagine that the `.datetimepicker()` method sets up the behavior on the element when run, so the way you have it right now, it doesn't get set up until you click, so naturally its special behavior won't be triggered until the next click. But then every click thereafter it gets re-setup again. Instead, you'll want to run the `datetimepicker()` immediately after the AJAX content is loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you're adding datepicker on click on #container - that's probably some div that wraps everything:

```
$("#container").on("click", "#datetimepicker1", function(){
  $("#datetimepicker1").datetimepicker({
    locale: 'nl',
    format: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
    allowInputToggle: true,
    useCurrent: false,
  }); 
});
```

So first time you click you're actually adding datepicker on your container, your code should look like this without any onclick event:

```
$("#datetimepicker1 input[name='invoicedate']").datetimepicker({
    locale: 'nl',
    format: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
    allowInputToggle: true,
    useCurrent: false,
});
```

You also need to wrap this up on element creation if this is done dynamically.

Comment: It doesn't work, it can't attach to datetimepicker1 in the dom before the AJAX content is loaded. What do you mean with element creation?

Comment: That's exactly what I mean by element creation - you're creating it dynamically on ajax call, so at the time you're creating element you can attach datepicker to it, I can help you with this but I need to see code when you're creating element - ajax success part - or even better exact moment where you create #datetimepicker1 td and where you append input box to it.

Comment: I looked at the javascript function that sends the ajax request and inserts the data with document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText; and I added the datetimepicker() part and it works now. Thank you.